# How do I change the git origin remote location of Homebrew in Mac OS X 10.8 (mountain lion)?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

In setting up my Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion environment ([per these instructions](http://sergeykarayev.com/work/2012-08-08/setting-up-mountain-lion/)), I am running into an issue with Homebrew after installing it and running `brew doctor` in the shell.

```
    Warning: Suspicious git origin remote found.

    With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't pull updates from
    the main repository. The current git origin is:

    Unless you have compelling reasons, consider setting the
    origin remote to point at the main repository, located at:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
```

How can I change the git origin remote location?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](http://lexsheehan.blogspot.com/2013/01/setting-up-homebrew-on-mac-mini.html), I discovered my issue.

When installing Homebrew, it doesn't seem to pull the latest version. After installation, run `brew update`. Homebrew more recently fixed the "Origin issue" in a later release which is reflected upon updating the installation.

Comment: +1! A small comment to this solution:

After installing homebrew today, I got the same warning. Running brew update however told me that homebrew was up to date. I had to restart my machine before I could use brew update and remove the warning (closing the terminal was not enough).

Comment: `brew update` caused the problem for me, but restarting Terminal solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my iMac to 10.9.1 and then did a `brew update`. After that `brew doctor` gave me the 'non-standard origin' warning.  The post referred to by @tom-geoco didn't really say what was wrong or explain how to manually change the 'origin remote' setting, but, as per @jesdisciple's comment above I just quit the Terminal, run it up again and tried `brew doctor` and the problem vanished.  `brew --config` now reports `ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git` which is correct. Spooky eh?

Answer (score 0):

Comment: (I do not have enough reputation to comment, so please add this and delete this)

1. brew update
2. brew doctor -> Suspicious origin error
3. restart terminal
4. brew doctor -> Suspicious origin error
5. brew update
6. restart terminal
7. brew doctor -> All ok.

This is how it was for me. I hope this helps someone else out there. Notice that you must run *brew update* **twice** to get rid of it.